# React-Hook-Form and validating

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

## Background

- I want to make a Number Input.
- This custom input accept only number and has character length limitation.
- Will be used with react-hook-form.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type NumberInputProps = {
    _maxLength?: number;
    name: string;
    className?: string;
    onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    placeholder?: string;
    value?: string;
};

const NumberInput = ({ _maxLength, className, name, onChange: handleChange, placeholder, value }: NumberInputProps) => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        setVal(value);
    }, [value]);

    const handleInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        alert("handleInput !");

        let value = e.target.value;
        if (_maxLength && value.length >= _maxLength) {
            value = value.slice(0, _maxLength);
        }
        setVal(value);
        handleChange?.(e);
    };

    const cn = `number-input ${className}`;

    return (
        <input name={name} className={cn} type="number" onInput={handleInput} placeholder={placeholder} value={val} />
    );
};

export default NumberInput;
```

## Problem

As you can see this component is Controlled Component.
But I don't want to use `useState`, `useEffect` because it makes the code too long.

Is there a shorter, more intuitive way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any value in using `useEffect()`.  Change your code to:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

type NumberInputProps = {
    _maxLength?: number;
    name: string;
    className?: string;
    onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    placeholder?: string;
    value?: string;
};

const NumberInput = ({ _maxLength, className, name, onChange: handleChange, placeholder, value }: NumberInputProps) => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(value);

    const handleInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        if (_maxLength && value.length >= _maxLength) {
            value = value.slice(0, _maxLength);
        }
        setVal(value);
        handleChange?.(value);
    };

    const cn = `number-input ${className}`;

    return (
        <input name={name} className={cn} type="number" onInput={handleInput} placeholder={placeholder} value={val} />
    );
};

export default NumberInput;
```

Note: the signature of `handleChange()` is modified as we are now giving it the `value` and not the event `e`.  You could give it `e` but then you need to duplicate the "value truncation" logic in `handleInput()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using react-hook-form. So don't need `useStates` anymore I think. I guess you can do something simple like this (Also you can create a common component if you want).

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

type FormValues = {
  myNumber: number;
};

const maxLength = 5;

function NumberInput({
  onChange,
  value,
}: {
  onChange: (value: number) => void;
  value: number;
}) {
  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(Number(e.target.value.slice(0, maxLength)));
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<FormValues>();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="myNumber"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <NumberInput onChange={onChange} value={value} />
        )}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but,I want to create a NumberInput for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

When using react-hook-form there is no need for most of your code. If you're open to making life even quicker and easier, here is a working example using react-hook-form and prime-react.

Both libs work very well together and have great documentation on how to use them (there are some extra css imports from templates to make everything look fancy but these arent needed)

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { InputNumber } from "primereact/inputnumber";
import "primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import { classNames } from "primereact/utils";

//code from github.com/XYIAN/hook-form-sandbox-js
export const MyForm = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur", // Trigger validation onBlur
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log('on submit hit with data:', data);
    //this is only hit when there is no errors in the fields
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="numberInput">Number Input:</label>
        <Controller
          name="numberInput"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={0}
          rules={{
            validate: (value) => {
              // Custom validation rule to limit input length to 10 characters
              return (
                String(value).length <= 10 ||
                "Input length cannot be greater than 10"
              );
            },
          }}
          render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
            <>
              <InputNumber
                id={field.name}
                inputRef={field.ref}
                value={field.value}
                onBlur={field.onBlur}
                onValueChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                useGrouping={false}
                inputClassName={classNames({ "p-invalid": fieldState.error })}
                showButtons
              />
              {fieldState.invalid && (
                <span className="p-error">{fieldState.error?.message}</span>
              )}
            </>
          )}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={formState.isSubmitting}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

The logic still works very similar for regular inputs just limited to HTML attributes